# Why undefined global variable throws exception but accessing via window does not?

Tags: javascript

**Behavior**

I have a global variable named `InfoPanel`. If I try to reference it via `InfoPanel` when it is `undefined` it throws an uncaught reference error for not being defined. However, if I reference it via `window.InfoPanel` it returned `undefined` as expected.

**Question**

Why does `InfoPanel !== undefined` throw an exception but `window.InfoPanel !== undefined` works as expected?

For those asking for code: https://jsfiddle.net/Angryr/w27ezsb3/

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Because you're describing code without showing it. Show enough code so that someone could reproduce the error condition you're describing.

Comment: InfoPanel !== undefined would throw if it was not *declared*, in which case you don't have an InfoPanel variable as stated.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I don't get why more code is needed. It is a question not about any specific piece of code it is about variable access and I've show snippests of both ways I've experienced.

Comment: Please put your code directly in your question instead of behind a link to another site (that not everyone has access to).

Comment: The only code that is needed to answer the question (Clearly because Phiter has answered it) is the `InfoPanel !== undefined` and `window.InfoPanel !== undefined`. Which **IS** in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you try to access `InfoPanel` globally, it tries to find a variable that doesn't exist. So it'll throw an exception.

When you do `window.InfoPanel`, it's trying to access an object property (the `InfoPanel` property of the `window` object).

The second form doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: Ah, I see that makes sense. I'll accept this answer once it lets me.

Comment: I'm trying to locate more resources so I can have a richer answer.